# Chrome extension browser action acts weird when switching tabs

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that works perfectly when I'm using it in one tab. Then I go to another tab and extension still works, but here's the strange thing that I can't understand. When I come back to first tab and I click on browser action to show the extension or close (if I left it open), nothing happens. I need to click browser action second time and then extension starts working.

Part of my background.js where the browser action button is defined:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {       
    if (page_loaded == true) {
        chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true, highlighted: true }, function (tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { greeting: "browser_action_clicked" }, function (response) {
                if (response.found == 'N') {
                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "src/injection.js" }, function () {
                        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "src/extension.js" }, function () {
                            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { code: "$('.cheap-watcher' ).animate({ 'right': '0px' }, 'slow');" }, function () {
                                sidebarActive = true;
                            });
                        });
                    });
                }
                else {
                    if (sidebarActive == true) {
                        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { code: "$('.cheap-watcher' ).animate({ 'right': '-370px' }, 'slow');" }, function () {
                            sidebarActive = false;
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { code: "$('.cheap-watcher' ).animate({ 'right': '0px' }, 'slow');" }, function () {
                            sidebarActive = true;
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }      
});
```

Did I wrote something wrong? Or is it chrome bug?

Comment: _"rest of the function that is unnesessary here"_ Or so you think.

Comment: Side note: you don't have to query for the active tab, you already have it from the `onClicked` event.

Comment: How does your `page_loaded` change? And also - did you attempt [debugging](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IP0nMv_NI1s) this?

Comment: Anyway, I can guess enough to answer this..

Comment: My page_loaded changes in chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener function when completed it's true when loading it is false. I didn't debugged it yet. It would like to hear your guess. And side note: after removing active: true extension threw error that my response is undefined. @Xan

Comment: You don't need to use `query` at all. You already have `tab` as an argument to the outermost listener - you don't need to query then take `tabs[0]`, just use `tab` (you're already mixing the two up, by the way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `sidebarActive` is stored as a global state variable (and same with `page_loaded`). So here's what you have as an example:

1. You click the button on your first tab; sidebar is shown, `sidebarActive` is set to true.
2. You do something with the second tab that results, eventually, in `sidebarActive` being false - no longer reflecting the state of the old tab.
3. You click the button on your first tab; since `sidebarActive` is false, you attempt to show the sidebar; however, it is already shown, so it gives an impression of doing "nothing".
4. However, now `sidebarActive` is actually in sync with the tab, so subsequent clicks "work".

This will not work at all, since the state is really per-tab. You have to either:

- Save the state in the content script, not the background script, or
- Save the state per-tab, e.g. as an array indexed by tab IDs: `sidebarActive[tab.id]`
  In this case, you may still need to do some cleanup on the array when tab updates happen.

Comment: P.S. Jumping to "is it a Chrome bug" is a very bold conclusion to make. Always consider yourself at fault by default unless you've completely eliminated the possibility.